# Print on stdout and log with logger

Tags: io-redirection, logger

I have a bash script with several "echo STRING" commands.  I would like to log STRING with logger but still print it on stdout. `echo STRING | logger` obliviously does not do it.

EDIT: `echo STRING | tee >(logger)` does it. >(COMMAND) is a process substitution, it substitutes the input to the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash you should be able to do this:

```
logger(){
  tee >(command logger)
}
```

Then pipe to `logger` as you did before.

If you wanted to implement this via a custom logging function, as suggested by Stephen Harris, this could be done like so:

```
logger(){
  tee >(command logger)
}

echolog(){
  printf '%s\n' "$@" | logger
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically write a logging function; something like

```
mylog()
{
  echo "$@"
  echo "$@" | logger
}

mylog "Hello, world!"
```

It gives flexibility on what you want to log, and can even let you do things like add a timestamp in front of lines if that's what you want.